# Can one external JavaScript file access DOM elements from multiple HTML files?

Tags: javascript, dom, null

This is a very basic question, but I'm a total JavaScript newbie...
Here's the situation: I have 3 HTML files, and I want to know if it's possible to use one external JavaScript file that interacts with elements from all the HTML files, and, in particular, takes values from one to use on another.

For example, HTML Page One has an input field and I want to take the value of the text entered into that input field and place it on HTML Page Two. Can that be done using only one external JavaScript file? If so, how do I specify that I'm accessing an element in the DOM of Page One to get the value to place in Page Two? The code in question is below.

When a user clicks on the loginButton on Page One, I want the greetUser function to put the value of inputUsername from Page One in the greeting element on Page Two:

````````````
document.getElementById("loginButton").addEventListener('click', greetUser);

function greetUser(){
    var greet=document.getElementById("inputUsername").value;
    document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML="Welcome, "+greet;
}
```````````

I get this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at greetUser
````````````

Comment: Does the user have both pages open?

Comment: Yes, both pages are open. However, in case it matters, these are just local files on my computer (this is for a class assignment).

Comment: That might make it tough. I'd have recommended using BroadcastChannel but I'm doubtful it works on file URIs

Comment: Transfer requests through URL? Similar to how some POST and GET forms work in PHP.

Comment: Is there a solution using only JavaScript?

Comment: hey @farGola did you find a solution here?

Comment: no, @Polem, I didn't